# Как добавить изображение внутрь ссылки?

Tags: php, wordpress

Данный код выводит изображение рядом с ссылкой, а необходимо внутрь ссылки:

```
add_filter( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'filter_walker_nav_menu_start_el', 10, 4 );
function filter_walker_nav_menu_start_el( $item_output, $item, $depth, $args ) {
  if ( ! empty( $item->classes ) && in_array( 'menu-item-has-children', $item->classes ) ) {
    $item_output .= '<img src="'. get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/images/icon.svg" alt="">';
  }

  return $item_output;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так
https://wp-kama.ru/hook/nav_menu_item_title

```
add_filter('nav_menu_item_title', 'filter_nav_menu_item_title', 10, 4);
function filter_nav_menu_item_title($title, $item, $args, $depth)
{
    $title = '<img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/icon.svg" alt="">' . $title;

    return $title;
}
```